# How to change the options for FullCalendar plugin?

Tags: jquery, events, calendar

In Rails 4.1.4, I am using gem 'fullcalendar_engine' for calendar events. Referred through https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine

`$('.calendar').fullCalendar(full_calendar_options);` If I used this line, I can create an events on a calendar but not able to change the UI(to add custom options).

If I used below code(custom options), Calendar theme will get change but not able to create an events(while clicking on any cell) and also already created events will not display.

```
var options = {
  theme: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  }
};

$('.calendar').fullCalendar(options);
```

or

```
$('.calendar').fullCalendar();  // events creation and display will not happen
```

In index.html.erb,

```
<p>
  <%= link_to 'Create Event', 'javascript:void()', id: 'new_event' %>
</p>
<div>
  <div class='calendar'></div>
</div>
<div id="event_desc_dialog" class="dialog" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="create_event_dialog" class="dialog" style ="display:none;">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
  var options = {
    theme: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
  };

  $('.calendar').fullCalendar(options);
  $('#new_event').click(function(event) {
    FullcalendarEngine.Form.display()
    event.preventDefault();
  });
 });
</script>
```

I have to complete this feature with UI changes and functionality fixes. Please help me solve this calendar issue.

Comment: What does your view code for this looks like?

Comment: Shruthi, could you tell me what the difference is between fullcalendar-rails and fullcalendar-rails-engine? I coudn't find a proper answer and I'm not sure which one I should choose.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297279/difference-between-fullcalendar-engine-rails-fullcalendar-rails-gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the `config/fullcalendar.yml` file to add custom options that will override defaults provided by `full_calendar_options` global JS variable. This will override the options for any calendar you instantiate.

If you want to override just for one calendar instance, you can use this code:

```
var options = {
  theme: true,
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  }
};

$('.calendar').fullCalendar($.extend(full_calendar_options,options));
```

You can see default fullcalendar options by fullcalendar_engine gem here:
https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine/blob/master/config/initializers/configuration.rb

Comment: For some reason fullcalendar.yml does not update, even when restarting the server.