# difference between fullcalendar-engine-rails fullcalendar-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

Does sby know what's the main difference between the fullcalendar-rails and the fullcalendar-engine-rails gem? I don't know which one I should pick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the engine version depends upon the non-engine one... Just looking at the readmes:

https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails

this is a rails implementation of the jquery plugin.
It lets you add the js into your asset pipeline by adding the gem to your gemfile instead of copy/pasting js into your app

https://github.com/vinsol/fullcalendar-rails-engine

This seems to be an engine implementation of the above - it appears to give you some nicer convenience methods on top of just bringing in the js.

Note: this is from a quick google and 30 seconds of skimming the readmes... I suggest you read them yourself to get more info.

As to "which one to choose"... can't help you if you don't tell us what you need it for. (also that's probably a bit beyond the scope of an S/O question.

Comment: Taryn, I'm pretty new to integrating js libs to rails. I read both, just was hard to decide if it's worth trying the second one or I could pull the things off based on the first. I would like to create/update events w/ drag&drop (fullcalendar itself is capable of this) that after changing persist in db rather than doing the old HTML CRUD way or even using bootstrap modal. Once it is done I would go for the google calendar API integration. So my main problem is that I can't decide if it's worth using the engine one and if the engine can cause any problem in my app.

Comment: We can't really decide that for you. My best advice is "suck it and see" - timebox a trial for about an hour's worth of work. Pick one and see how easy it is to integrate it. Worst case scenario is you've lost an hour of work and learned a bit about how to integrate it.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I just thought sby has already been thru this situation as this one is a pretty common feature.

Comment: probably... but it's not really a Stack-overflow-style question. Stack Overflow works best for specific, technical questions that have one right answer... rather than "which one should I choose" questions - which encourage debate.

Comment: Taryn, thx for the insight! I have some technical questions regarding this over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34323316/fullcalendar-with-rails-ajax-put-request-is-not-working. Could you take a look at it? You would save my life. I hope this format fits the stackoverflow-style question, let me know if doesn't. Thanks a lot!